# Visual Studio Code causing blue screen of death on Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, bsod

I have Visual Studio Code version 1.22.2 running on Windows. When working on Javascript code, it crashes and causes a blue screen with the following technical info:

```
STOP: 0X0000007E
mfeavfk.sys - Address <...>
```

I have a plugin for MS SQL and a beautify plugin installed.

Comment: This sounds like you should report it as a bug to VS code, their community page has a link to github for that purpose: https://www.github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new

Comment: You need to go shopping for a better anti-malware product.  McAfee is not what you ever want to use on a programming machine, it is the kind of crapware that is not resilient to programming tools that make executable files appear from seemingly no-where.  The one included with the OS is best.

Answer (score 2):

I recently updated Windows and started experiencing BSODs every time I started VS Code. Here's how I fixed it - hopefully this helps someone else:

1. Open a command prompt and type the following command:

```
code --disable-extensions
```

If your computer doesn't BSOD after this step, then an extension is likely causing the issue.

2. Press `ctrl+shift+x` to open the extensions sidebar
3. Under `disabled`, uninstall any extensions you aren't using or don't recognize.
4. Restart VS Code, and see if it still crashes.
5. If step 3 didn't help, try removing all extensions and then reinstalling one at a time until you find one that causes the crash. Then repeat steps 1-4, this time removing the extension you identified as causing the crash.